# Set QGIS extent from browser?

Tags: qgis

I have a list of locations in a database, that is shown in a browser in a very user friendly fashion. Sometimes the user needs to open one of these locations in QGIS to edit. I would like to put a link in the HTML, maybe a geo URI, so that when the user clicks the link, QGIS will open at the correct location. Currently the user has to manually pan to the location for each location.

Is this possible?

**Reply to security concerns:** SpacedMan commented "Having a web browser link that when clicked starts running an application on your PC would have all sorts of malicious uses". Good point. However, I am not thinking of a link that would work universally for every user, I'm thinking of a type of link where the user could choose that such links should result in an action in QGIS.

Similar to how the following html opens whatever user email client that the user has chosen as his default `<a href='mailto:foo@bar.com'>email</a>`.

Smart phones also opens various links in whatever app the user has chosen for those links.

Comment: Having a web browser link that when clicked starts running an application on your PC would have all sorts of malicious uses, so I don't think its possible. 
You could have a button on the web page that copies the extent to the user's clipboard, and then paste that into QGIS to set the extent.

Comment: @Spacedman: Good point. Please see the edit I made to my question.

Comment: Guess it would be much better to directly use your database as QGIS datasource. Your users could easily zoom to every location using the attribute table. The "Quick Finder" plugin would be ideal, but unfortunately it's not maintained anymore.

Comment: @Christoph: Only using QGIS attribute table is extremely limited to what can be achieced with common web programming. The web page is already there. Most users will use it for getting an overview, and only a few users will need to go and inspect features in QGIS. I want to make it easy and convenient for those users.

Comment: @MadsSkjern maybe a small Python plugin with a simple toolbar would be an alternative. Driving QGIS from a Webpage is a no go unless QGIS is available as WebAssembly 